# Ошибка командной строки NameError: name 'null' is not defined для Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Есть задача.

Напишите программу, которая запускается из консоли и печатает значения всех переданных аргументов на экран (имя скрипта выводить не нужно). Не изменяйте порядок аргументов при выводе.

Для доступа к аргументам командной строки программы подключите модуль sys и используйте переменную `argv` из этого модуля.

Пример работы программы:

> python3 my_solution.py arg1 arg2

`arg1 arg2`

Т.е. на выводе должно быть ['все аргументы командной строки кроме имени файла', 'arg1', 'arg2']

Я пишу код через программную среду Jupyter-notebook. Когда запускаю код непосредственно в jupyter, то на выход получаю список аргументов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запустить программу через командную строку(запускаю командную строку из папки где лежит файл) появляется ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Если запустить команду dir, то файл видно.
2. Если запустить python в командной строке и прописать

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

То выводит: `['']`

В чем может быть причина ошибки?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В файлах с расширением ipynb находятся не скрипты Python, соответственно их нельзя запустить с помощью Python. Откройте любой текстовый редактор, создайте файл my_task.py, вставьте в него код, сохраните и запускайте.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!!! Да воздаться тебе добрый человек!

Answer (score -1):

возможно я не правильно понял вопрос, но мне кажется вы не указали в коде что именно нужно подавать на консоль, попробуйте так

from sys import argv

argA = argv[1]
argB = argv[2]

print(argA, argB)

Comment: Проблема была в расширении файла. По всей видимости код из файла с расширением .ipynb просто не мог быть вызван. Sergey Gornostaev (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev) правильно указал причину.